# Split Json Output and assign it to two different object

Tags: java, json, shell

Here Is My Java: Where it will run shell script and get output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/test.sh");
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(line);
        System.out.println("Parsed JSON : " + jSONObject);

    }
}
```

}

Here is my output :

```
Parsed JSON : {"network-metrics":{"interfaces":["eth0",{"status":{"TX":{"carrier":"0","bytes":"54835108","dropped":"0","overruns":"0","packets":"356928","errors":"0"},"RX":{"bytes":"739960761","dropped":"68","overruns":"0","packets":"766292","errors":"0","frame":"0"}}},"lo",{"status":{"TX":{"carrier":"0","bytes":"185357","dropped":"0","overruns":"0","packets":"967","errors":"0"},"RX":{"bytes":"185357","dropped":"0","overruns":"0","packets":"967","errors":"0","frame":"0"}}},"mlan0",{"status":{"TX":{"carrier":"0","bytes":"30056","dropped":"0","overruns":"0","packets":"542","errors":"0"},"RX":{"bytes":"275867466","dropped":"0","overruns":"7229","packets":"272573","errors":"272573","frame":"0"}}}]}}
Parsed JSON : {"os-metrics":{"NumberOfProcess":"242","Up Time":"8 hours, 7 minutes","Disk Usage":"33%","CPU Usage":"5.77916%"}}
```

So here. How can i assign network-metric and os-metrics to two different object

Comment: Can you explain your requirement better? Provide a sample output.

Comment: This java will be running my sh file on my disk. And java will print my shell output like given above. So here i have 2 json format ie) network-metrics and os-metrics. but its getting assigned to single one on my code **JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(line);** can I split into with line space ?

Comment: my expected output should get assigned to two different object. Is there any possible way ? 1st line one object and 2nd to another object

Comment: Yes! That works great. But the thing is object is getting printed **null** for second time.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it out now. You are iterating it in a `while` loop, you will only get one value at a time. You need to store it  so that it can fetched outside the loop

Comment: Awesome! That works fine. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/test.sh");
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;

    // Initialize 2 JSON Objects
    JSONObject networkMetrics = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject osMetrics = new JSONObject();

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(line);

        System.out.println("Parsed JSON : " + jSONObject);

        // Get the JSON Objects if they exist
        if (jSONObject.has("network-metrics")) {
             networkMetrics = jSONObject.getJSONObject("network-metrics");
             System.out.println("Network Metrics JSON : " + networkMetrics);
        }
        if (jSONObject.has("os-metrics")) {
             osMetrics = jSONObject.getJSONObject("os-metrics");
             System.out.println("OS Metrics JSON : " + osMetrics);
        }   
    }
}
```